# primary key of newly added row in sql table, vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, primary-key

I have a vb.net application where datagridview is databound to sql table at design time(with table adapter and dataset). All I wanted is to get newly added row's Primary key(int) when i add new row to it. I have searched, but it's showing sql commands like below:

```
    INSERT INTO #Customers
       (Name) 
    VALUES ('Customer 1')

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

so using scope_identity(). But is there any way I can do it with adapter(or dataset) in vb.net or same command can be given though adapter or similar ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try this!

SCOPE_IDENTITY() will give you the last identity value inserted into any table directly within the current scope (scope = batch, stored procedure, etc. but not within, say, a trigger that was fired by the current scope)

Use the OUTPUT clause if you are inserting multiple rows and need to retrieve the set of IDs that were generated.

```
INSERT #a(x)  OUTPUT inserted.identity_column VALUES('b'),('c');
```

--
result will be

```
1
2
```

Comment: how should i get index it into vb.net variable? I am new to vb.net and sql too.

Comment: you can declare a variable and execute the insert statement dim getValue as string = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: I am getting error: could not find stored procedure 'insert into customers(name) values('test'); select scope_identity()' at t= mycomm.executescalar() line

Comment: Dim str As String = "insert into testtable (Text,value) values ('Code','200'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
        cmd.Prepare()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim value As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        value you can see it's showing last inserted count

Comment: Thanks its working! I was wondering if there is any command in vb or function on dataset that will give me same answer? I mean because I am using datasource added at design time so dont use sql command to connect to database and all

Comment: you can but after inserting the values into table write the query to select the data into dataset object . Dim str As String = "select * from testtable;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Result;"
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(str, con)
        da.Fill(ds)
        'if you want to get the scope value use ds.tables(1)
        If (ds.Tables.Count > 0) Then
            Dim result As String = ds.Tables(1).Rows(0)("Result")
        End If